# Windows 10 after creators update - wifi disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm hopeless with this issue. So after W10 update (creators update) wifi on both laptops (Asus X553MA) seems not to function properly. What's the issue - WIFI drops randomly the connection. After that i have to manually click "connect" on specific network/ssid. What I've already did:

- updated W10 to newest updates/drivers etc
- adapter drivers removal/install
- netsh winsock reset
- wifi sense disabled
- no bios updates available
- checked if network adapter has enabled power saving option (disabled)
- disabled Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
- Removed WAN Miniports from device manager/network [this was a recommendation of asus official support]
- fast startup is disabled

At the moment I cannot use wired Internet, im forced to work on wifi. As you might assume this issue is anoying for laptop users (especially while working on software which requires instant wifi connection). Do you have any ideas what i can do more?

Comment: Is it happening with all networks or just yours?

Comment: Hmm I've never thought it might be the case of specific wifi. but im pretty confident it will the issue on all wifi's.

Comment: I would test it. It could have been just a coincidence it happening after the upgrade and  what really changed was at the router/AP or it needs a reboot.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a laptop of one of my customers. The intel chip drivers would update which would literally crash the wifi card. I solved it by reinstalling windows, which seemed to be the only way.

Comment: @LPChip did you format the hdd or just used the in-built windows tool to reinstall it?

Comment: I used the Media Creation Toolkit to create a USB installer, and used that. The format was done during the install. To clarify, it was an older laptop. He bought a new one from us but wanted to see if a reinstall would fix that issue so he could give the laptop to his daughter.